# Как нескольким пользователям обновлять презентаций в PowerPoint если в них есть связка с таблицами Excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint

Есть презентация в PowerPoint которая в себе содержит графики из связанных таблиц Excel, в свою очередь эти таблицы содержат в себе запросы в Power Query. Т.е. все это имеет жесткую привязку к местоположению файла и при перемещении приходится делать все связки заного что крайне долго.

У меня стоит задача что бы эти презентации могли обновлять несколько сотрудников без дополнительных манипуляций со связками файлов. Даже не знаю как к этому подступиться с чего начать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробывал разместить файлы в OneDrive, но не помогло, привязка все равно идет к местоположению на моем диске, по этому коллеги могут просматривать/редактировать файлы но связи не работают(

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все гораздо проще, решили проблему перемещением всех файлов на сетевую папку с VPN доступом.